# Mimic CI headless test in intellij on linux

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, junit

I have a CI machine running my Junit tests.. and there's a couple of tests that seem to not fail, but have several errors that seem related to the CI Server not having a graphics card. 
Is there a way in Intellij to mimic the way that the CI machine runs the tests, ie without a display

Thanks

Comment: Try running with `-Djava.awt.headless=true` VM Option.

Comment: excellent, thanks - i had searched and found that, but didn't realize it went into the VM options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Djava.awt.headless=true` added in the Run/Debug configuration **VM Options** field will do the job.